# An explicit formula for characteristic polynomial of matrix tensor product

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, symmetric-polynomials, resultants

Consider two polynomials P and Q and their companion matrices. It seems that char polynomial of tensor product of said matrices would be a polynomial with roots that are all possible pairs product of roots of P,Q.

I guess its coefficients could be expressed through coefficients of P and Q.
But I don't know the explicit formula and I cannot find it. I also failed to find it out myself -- I tried different approaches. Maybe it should be that characteristic polynomial, maybe resultant of some form, but..

I hope this is done by someone already.

I'll try to give an example
$c_0 = a_0^nb_0^m$, or maybe $c_0 = (-1)^{n+m}a_0^nb_0^m$ ($m,n$ are the degrees of $P and Q$.

$c_1 = a_0^{n-1}a_1b_0^{m-1}b_1$, this is one is probably incorrect, but I obviously cannot provide the correct answer if I don't know it yet.
It looks like $c_i$ is a sum of some sort.

Comment: Funny, how this is discussed here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188814/characteristic-polynomial-of-kronecker-tensor-product
(all this I know)
but no explicit formula given(

Comment: I don't see what more you want than what's given in the answer: if $F(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $P$, and $G(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $G$, then the characteristic polynomial of the tensor product should be (if I haven't made a mistake) the resultant with respect to $y$ of $G(y), F(\frac{x}{y})$, multiplied by a power of $y$.

Comment: I want the answer of a form:
Let's say a_i, b_j are coeffs of P and Q,and c_k are coeffs of what I want)

The answer would look like
c_k = f(a_i,b_j).
I want the explicit f.

Comment: A resultant can be expressed as the determinant of the Sylvester matrix; the Sylvester matrix is explicit in the $a_i, b_j$, and the formula for a determinant is well-known. Does that answer the question? If not, I don't see what would; the formulae depend on the degrees of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Degree of P is n, degree of Q is m.
Are you saying there is no generic formula at all?

Comment: I know the formula for determinant) I want cancellation of terms (this is what I couldn't do myself)

Comment: It's hard to believe, but if somebody else doesn't understand the question, I'll try to provide another clarification, although I am not sure what else can I say.

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate, though I accidentally voted to close as off topic.

Comment: Is there an answer somewhere?

Comment: A computer algebra system can compute the resultant explicitly to give you the formula f(a_i,b_j). But there's likely no formula for the generic case other than the one based on the Sylvester matrix. Since this answer was already given in the question you linked, yours is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Characteristic polynomial of Kronecker/tensor product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188814/characteristic-polynomial-of-kronecker-tensor-product)

Comment: Well, okay, I ll go and try it myself. I am pretty confident there is one, as sot as I find it, I'll post it here I guess.